# R: Loop a data frame, select rows and data point and render a R Markdown report

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

Everyone,

I am having an issue with my loop and maybe you can help or suggest something better.

Data Frame = df1

```
PARK     WTG        WEA       FEONOFF    CODE           TEXT                 
MOZART   82262  08 WEA 82262  FE_FM1667  FM1667   PIT Critical I2t Sum Max 187 
MOZART   82257  07 WEA 82257  FE_FM1667  FM1667   PIT Critical I2t Sum Max 62
```

df1 can go on for an `i` amount of rows.

I am using the below code:

```
SiWTG <- c()
for (i in 1:nrow(df1)) { 
SW <- data.table(df1[i,])
SW <- data.table(SW)
SWTG <- data.table(unlist(SW[1])) #unlist table to pull out vectors
wtgNumber <- as.numeric(SWTG[2])  # vector needed for R Markdown report
FMCode <- as.character(SWTG[5])   # vector needed for R Markdown report
PARK <- as.character(SWTG[1])     # vector needed for R Markdown report

render("USASickWTGCSS.rmd", output_file = paste0(PARK, "-", wtgNumber,"-SickWTG.html"))

SiWTG <- SW
}
```

This works for the first row in the loop of the data frame (df1). Then I keep getting this error:

```
Error in name_dots(...) : could not find function "name_dots"
```

Comment: What packages are you using? Only `rmarkdown`?

Comment: I cannot find reference to `name_dots` in either the `rmarkdown` or `knitr` packages. Is there something within `"USASickWTGCSS.rmd"` that references that function or variable?

Comment: When I get back to the office I will look again. Thanks

Comment: It may be a [helper function](https://rdrr.io/cran/data.table/src/R/utils.R) in `data.table`. The only other reference I see is from [bigdfr](https://github.com/privefl/bigdfr/blob/master/R/FDF.R).

Comment: So I fixed the issues.  I do believe it had something to do with the data.table package. I uninstalled and reinstalled and it is working great. Thank you all for you help.